# Display selected data from database using AlertDialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alertdialog

> Hi im trying to display the specific or selected data from database using alert dialog however the data i want to display doesn't display to alertDialog by the way im using floor for my database im pretty stack on this any suggestion or idea will be well appreciated.

Here is my code

```
Widget buildAboutDialog(BuildContext context,
      AddContactCallback _contactscreen, bool isEdit, ContactObject _contactObject)  {
      final databases = $FloorContactDatabase.databaseBuilder('Contacts.cb').build();
      if(contactObject != null) {
        this.contactObject = _contactObject;
        tfirstname.text = _contactObject.firstname;
        tlastname.text = _contactObject.lastname;
        tbirthday.text = _contactObject.birthday;
        tcontactnumber = _contactObject.contactnumber as TextEditingController ;
        tprofilepicture = _contactObject.profilepicture as File;
      } else {
        print('ERROR');
        print(tfirstname.value);
      }
      return new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text(isEdit ? 'Contact!' : 'Contact'),
        content: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 70,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xff476cfb),
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: new SizedBox(
                    width: 180.0,
                    height: 180.0,
                    child: (_image != null) ? Image.file(_image, // Image.file(File('${_contactsDao.profilepicture}'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ) : Image.network(
                      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502164980785-f8aa41d53611?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ),
              getTextFieled("First Name", tfirstname),
              getTextFieled("Last Name", tlastname),
              getTextFieled("Birth day", tbirthday),
              getTextFieled("Contact No", tcontactnumber),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
```

**And here is the functions and instance**

```
    Widget getTextFieled(
      String inputData, TextEditingController inputTextController) {
      var btm = new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child:  new  TextFormField(
            controller: inputTextController,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: inputData,
            ),
          ),
        );
      return btm;
 }

 Widget getAppButton (String buttonLabel, EdgeInsets margin){
    var btm = new Container(
      margin: margin,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFF28324E)),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(6.0)),
      ),
      child: new Text(
          buttonLabel,
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: const Color(0xFF28324E),
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            letterSpacing: 0.3,
          ),
      ),
    );
    return btm;
 }

 ContactObject getdata(bool isEdit) {
    return new ContactObject(
      firstname: tfirstname.text,
     lastname: tfirstname.text,
     birthday: tbirthday.text,
     contactnumber: int.parse(tcontactnumber.text),
      profilepicture: tprofilepicture.readAsStringSync(),
    );
 }

 onTap(bool isEdit, AddContactCallback addContactCallback, BuildContext context) {
    if(isEdit) {
      addContactCallback.updateContacts(getdata(isEdit));
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      print('ANG PUMASOK');
      print(tfirstname);
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'ERROR ERROR',
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM
      );
    }
 }


}

abstract class AddContactCallback {
    void updateContacts(ContactObject contactObject);
}
```

here is the Screenshot of my idea

[image: here is the Screenshot of my idea]

Comment: Can you please provide the getTextFieled method?

Comment: Hi @Tipu please my edited post Thanks for the response

Comment: ok ok ok, one minute, can you share all your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method has been used for a long time to modify an item in a list or other.

**This code is just an example of how it works.**

in base widget write this:

```
class BaseWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BaseWidgetState createState() => new _BaseWidgetState();
}

class _BaseWidgetState extends State<BaseWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // get data from data base
    _getDataFromDataBase();
    super.initState();
  }

  var _listComingDataFromDataBase;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _listComingDataFromDataBase == null
          ? Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () async {
                _getDataFromDataBase();
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      _buildAlertDialog(
                          context,
                          _listComingDataFromDataBase[
                              index]); //open dialog and send selected object
                    },
                  );
                },
                itemCount: _listComingDataFromDataBase.length,
              ),
            ),
    );
  }

  void _buildAlertDialog(context, selectedObject) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: AlertDialog(
          content: EditObjectWidget(selectedObject),
        )).then((isEdited) {
      if (isEdited) {
        // you can reload data from database
        _getDataFromDataBase();
      }
    });
  }

  void _getDataFromDataBase() {
    // database.getData.then((data){setState(){_listComingDataFromDataBase = data};});
  }
}
```

Create **EditObjectWidget** Like this:

```
class EditObjectWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final selectedObject;

  EditObjectWidget(this.selectedObject);

  @override
  _EditObjectWidgetState createState() => _EditObjectWidgetState();
}

class _EditObjectWidgetState extends State<EditObjectWidget> {
  final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _numberController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    fillFields(widget.selectedObject);
    super.initState();
  }

  void fillFields(selectedObject) {
    _firstNameController.text = selectedObject.fistName ?? '';
    if (selectedObject.number != null)
      _numberController.text = selectedObject.number.toString();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _firstNameController.dispose();
    _numberController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          controller: _firstNameController,
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: _numberController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _updateObject();
          },
          child: Text('Submit'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void _updateObject() {
    //update object in data base
    // database.updateObject({'number':_numberController.text,'first_name':_firstNameController.text});
    //if updateObject method return true, close dialog with true result, Otherwise false
    bool isEdited = true;
    if(!isEdited)
    {
      //show validation error, or another
    }
    else
    Navigator.pop(context, isEdited);
  }
}
```

I did not use your code, it is only an explanation

**Hope this code helps you**

Comment: Hi @faouk Thank you so much for your effort really appreciated to stuff god bless solve my problem Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the value needs to be set to `TextFormField` after setting the  `TextEditingController` for it.

Try before returning the widget, set a value;

```
Widget getTextFieled(
      String inputData, TextEditingController inputTextController) {
      var btm = new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child:  new  TextFormField(
            controller: inputTextController,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              hintText: inputData,
            ),
         ),
      );
      inputTextController.text = "Some Value Test";
      return btm;
 }
```

Comment: yap i will modify it Thanks for ide @Shri